# Surface integral of a scalar function in the first octant

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I am having difficulty drawing and parameterizing the surface for the integral 
$$
\iint_s x^2z\,dS\ 
$$  s: 1st octant part of $y=x^2\ $ cut by $2x+y+z=1$

Comment: Where do y=x^2 and 2x+y+z=1 intersect?

Comment: There are 2 possibilities for the area s.  It also has to be specified whether s is with the yz plane or xz plane before getting an answer.

Comment: I wrote down the question wrong as dxdy should have been dS but other than that, its all the information given to me in the question.